# How to document the rest of argv in golang flags?

Tags: go, command-line-arguments

As a microservices author, I appreciate how powerful the standard library's flag pacakge is, providing a lightweight way to document command line flags. However, the built-in `-help` option appears to present documentation for only the flags themselves, while the rest of the command line arguments are often idiosyncratic, requiring documentation as well. What is a good way to document the rest of the CLI arguments, such as a Go application that accepts some flags, and then treats the rest of the arguments as file paths?

Answer (score 6):

My preferred approach is just to set [`flag.Usage`](https://godoc.org/flag#pkg-variables) to a function which prints the additional documentation.

For example:

```
flag.Usage = func() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "usage: %s [flags] <paths...>\n", os.Args[0])
    flag.PrintDefaults()
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Argument documention goes here\n")
}
```